# undefined reference to `WinMain@16' with a main

Tags: c++, scite

I have a really simple shell of of a program. The editor i use is Scite and my compiler is MingW.

The answer to this is that I'm missing a main but i do have a main().

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Money.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{


}
```

Money.cpp

```
#include "Money.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

Money::Money()
{
    cout << "test"

}
```

Money.h

```
#ifndef MONEY_H 
#define MONEY_H

class Money 
{
   public:
      Money();
   private:

};

 #endif //MONEY_H
```

Everytime I try to compile Money.cpp it gives me the error

libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

And I'm not sure what's wrong with the program. All the files are in the same directory. I'm fairly new to programming in C++ so if you can give me a very basic answer or fix it be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What commands are you using for compilation?

Comment: Somewhere in your project you are building (linking) this as a Windows program. But what you want is a console program.

Comment: I use scite as my editor and MingW as my compiler. To compile i just use "compile" option on scite

Comment: did not understand that answer  @martze

Comment: OT: I hope it doesn't give that error when you just compile `Money.cpp`. That appears to be a *link-time* error due to an unresolved external (and I concur with Martze; read the linked answer in his comment).

Comment: indeed the error only happens when i compile Money.cpp...

Answer (score 0):

[`WinMain` is the entry point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of Windows "Win32" programs.

You are probably using Visual Studio wizard to create your C++ project, but you chose a *Windows C++ application*. Such an application is expected to have `WinMain()` as an entry point (the `@16` part is name mangling decorations, according to Visual C++ compiler rules), but you haven't provided that in your code.

If you want to build a C++ console-mode application (with the classical standard `main()` entry point), you may want to choose the **Win32 Console Application** option when creating a new project with Visual Studio.

E.g. this is a screenshot from Visual Studio 2010:

[image: Win32 Console Application option for new project in Visual Studio 2010]

Comment: I don't use visual studio, i use Scite as my editor

Comment: Ah, sorry, I don't know Scite. Anyway, you may want to edit your post adding some details on your toolchain, so people can give better help.